# Mockito возвращает NullPointerException

Tags: java, junit, mockito

При тестировании метода, возвращающего список сущностей, вылетает NullPointerException.

Код тестового класса:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class ApplicationServiceImplTest {

    private List<Book> booksList;

    @Mock
    private BookRepository repository;

    @InjectMocks
    private ApplicationServiceImpl applicationService;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        booksList = new ArrayList<>();
        booksList.add(new Book("Heidi","Unknown"));
        booksList.add(new Book("The Normal Christian Life","Unknown"));
        booksList.add(new Book("GAPS","Unknown"));
        booksList.add(new Book("The Well-Behaved Child","Unknown"));
        booksList.add(new Book("Life Skills for Kids","Unknown"));
        booksList.add(new Book("iBlog","Unknown"));
        booksList.add(new Book("Unwired Mom","Unknown"));
        booksList.add(new Book("The Voyage of the Dawn Treader","Unknown"));
        booksList.add(new Book("Doctor Dolittle","Unknown"));
        booksList.add(new Book("Spell to Write and Read","Unknown"));

    }

    @Test
    void getAllEntitiesTest() {

        when(repository.getBooks()).thenReturn(booksList);

        List<Book> all = applicationService.getAllBooks();

        verify(repository, times(1)).getBooks();
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(all.toArray(), booksList.toArray());

    }
}
```

Текст ошибки:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at application.services.ApplicationServiceImplTest.justTest(ApplicationServiceImplTest.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:389)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:163)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:110)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:83)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот этот код

```
@InjectMocks
private ApplicationServiceImpl applicationService = new ApplicationServiceImpl();
```

А также возможно еще одна ошибка возникающая при стартапе

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

этого делать нет необходимости, так как это происходит при выполнении `MockitoJUnitRunner`.

Comment: Не помогло, ошибка осталась прежней.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, что вам не помогло? Как воспроизвести вашу ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

Такое ощущение, что Мокито не смог правильно заинжектить зависимости. Вот что говорит документаци:

> Mockito will try to inject mocks only either by constructor injection,
>   setter injection, or property injection in order and as described
>   below. If any of the following strategy fail, **then Mockito won’t
>   report failure;** i.e. you will have to provide dependencies yourself.

У вас в классе `ApplicationServiceImpl` только одна дополнительная зависимость на `BookRepository` ? Если есть другие, то проинициализируйте их явно через @Mock. Есть вероятность, что не все зависимости были удовлетворены и он свалился с ошибкой.

Также есть у вас есть возможность самостоятельно инициализировать класс `ApplicationServiceImpl`, попробуйте что-то в этом духе:

```
  @InjectMocks
  private ApplicationServiceImpl applicationService;

  @Before
  public void setUp(){

    booksList = new ArrayList<>();
    booksList.add(new Book("Heidi","Unknown"));
    .....
    booksList.add(new Book("Spell to Write and Read","Unknown"));

    applicationService = new ApplicationServiceImpl();
    applicationService.setBookRepository(repository);

    //или через конструктор 
    applicationService = new ApplicationServiceImpl(repository);
}
```

Если все отработает, то надо будет разбираться почему не сработал авто-инжект у Мокито

Comment: А что если у меня сервис имеет зависимости на два других сервиса, которые в свою очередь имеют зависимости на репозитории. Репозитории тоже будут моками?